# Does CartoDB support Retina screens?

Tags: carto, visualisation, mobile

We are using CartoDB as our production mapping solution.

Just wondering does it offers support for **Retina** screens and if so how hard can be to toggle on?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using the latest version of CartoDB (which should be the default), your maps should be supported on Retina screens. This support seems to be automatic within the program, rather than requiring a toggle on or off.

A brief description of the improvements in the latest versions of CartoDB:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/releases
(Note that as of Feb '14 mobile maps are supported on retina screens); https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cartodb/8Vyc6xrzI7g/OGqxDFlbg44J

Comment: cartodb does not support retina yet (07/21/2014)